# Are there any planned missions for spacecraft leaving the solar system?

Tags: future-missions, solar-system

We have some spacecraft that have extended missions outside of the solar system (ie voyager), but are there any plans for new spacecraft that will leave our solar system either by a primary or extended mission?

Comment: AFAIU the extra stellar missions so far launched all depended on a rare alignment of planets for the purposes of gravity assists. No propulsion system we've yet devised makes extra-stellar missions practical without the gravity assists.

Comment: @AndrewThompson If so, do you know when the next such opportunity will arise and if there are any plans for that moment?

Comment: I don't know for sure, but as far as I *vaguely* recall, such fortuitous planetary alignments occur every couple of centuries.

Comment: Oh wait.. look at [Grand Tour program](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grand_Tour_program) *"The **particular alignment** occurs once every 175 years."* Mind you, that was to visit all the outer planets, whereas you'd skip Pluto (oops! Not even a planet any longer) if you were most interested in gravity assists.

Comment: What would the scientific purpose be for such a mission?

Comment: @GdD I don't know, but I'm confident we can find scientific value in sending probes out of the solar system.

Comment: If you mean "new" as "mission has not been launched yet", I don't know, except for Breakthrough Starshot.  But if you mean "new" as "newer than Voyager", then New Horizons is already on an escape trajectory from the solar system, but its making at least one more stop in the Kuiper Belt first.

Comment: Voyager and New Horizons were launched years apart, but not 175 years apart, and both are on escape trajectories.

Comment: Define "planned". Breakthrough Starshot exists, money's being spent on research, but it's a long ways from actually being done.

Comment: @Cody Not launched yet.

Comment: @DylanSp Lets call it anything with a scheduled launch date.

Answer (score 0):

There are no *official* and *founded* plans of *new* mission with primary plan to leave the Solar System.